# Adding Values to a List from a function in Matlab

Tags: list, matlab, overwrite

I'm trying to write a code that searches a list and matches a term. In this case 'bus' what I am then trying to do is to get the values for distance and time for that method and add them to separate lists. Attached is my code

```
distanceb = [];
timeb = [];
for i =1:n
 if strcmp(method(i),'bus') == 1
  distanceb = (x(i))
  timeb = time(i)
 end
end
```

I can get the values for the x and time but the code seems to overwrite everytime it adds to the list and I get only one answer for distanceb and timeb. Is there a way to add the values to the list without overwriting the previous value?

Comment: Don't use all caps in your titles.

Comment: @RobertHarvey better?

Comment: Of course. Did you expect me to say something else?

Comment: @RobertHarvey no. Can you help with the problem?

Comment: Eh, I'm just a lowly moderator, helping to sweep the floors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning new values to `distanceb` and `timeb` as scalars and not as lists/vectors.
You need to append values:

```
 distanceb(end+1) = x(i);
 timeb(end+1) = time(i);
```

A few remarks:

1. If you know the final size of `distanceb` and `timeb` it is best to pre-allocate them and not grow them inside the loop.
2. It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was trying to append using the append function earlier but got stuck on the problem. It does make sense now you have pointed out the error. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user2423678 I'm glad you found my answer useful. Please consider "accepting" it by clicking the "V" icon beside it. It would also be nice if you find this answer upvote-worthy.

Comment: One final question the output of this is in lots of columns (one column for each result) is there a way to get all the outputs into one column?

Comment: @user2423678 you can use `(:)` operator to stack a matrix into a single column.

Comment: Yes but where do I/would I place this is in the code. Im new at matlab and unsure? Sorry